# Get text inside element using cursor position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project I'm using the great and useful [jQuery TextRange](https://github.com/dwieeb/jquery-textrange/) plugin. I have a highlight div in the top of an textarea and I must know what's the actual element the user was editing. To understand better, I will use a lot of examples bellow.

In my project, if I have this text on textarea:

```
Text that doesn't matter #this_matter and #this_too
```

I have something like this in my highlight div:

```
"Text that doesn't matter <b>#this_matter</b> and #this_too</b>"
```

---

### Everything is okay, but...

I need know what's the "hashtag" I'm editing. So I think fix this using positions, but as you will see, I have some questions. In my textarea I get the cursor position using:

```
input = $('#post-input')
var cursorPosition = input.textrange('get','position')
```

With this information I need know what's the hashtag I'm editting. Assume that `|` is the symbol of where the cursor is in the textarea, so:

```
"Text that doesn't matter #this_matter and #this|_too"
```

Must return `<b>#this_too</b>` element, because this is the actual hashtag. Another example:

```
 "Text that doesn't matter #|this_matter and #this_too"
```

Must return `<b>#this_matter</b>`.

After that all, how I can return the right element with cursor position information?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**document.elementFromPoint**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint):

```
document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
```